Nginx permission problem [nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)]
I am trying to run Nginx on Openshift but facing this directory permissions issues.
Nginx permission problem [nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/cache/nginx/client_temp" failed (13: Permission denied)]
from the dockerfile
# Custom base image java with Fedora OS and has been scanned using snyk
FROM nginx:alpine

# Set variable TZ for timezone at Asia/Jakarta
ENV TZ="Asia/Jakarta"

# Install tzdata and set timezone with environtment variable TZ
RUN apk add tzdata \
    && cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

# Initialization directory
WORKDIR /app

# Create user
RUN addgroup --system adm-app \
    && adduser -DH --system adm-app --ingroup adm-app

ADD ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Create folder
RUN mkdir -p /var/run/nginx \
    && touch /var/run/nginx/nginx.pid \
    && chmod 644 /var/run/nginx/nginx.pid \
    && mkdir -p /var/log/nginx \
    && mkdir -p /var/cache/nginx

# Add permission in folder /app and folder used for nginx
RUN chown -R adm-app:adm-app /app && chmod -R 755 /app \
    && chown -R adm-app:adm-app /var/cache/nginx \
    && chown -R adm-app:adm-app /var/log/nginx \
    && chown -R adm-app:adm-app /etc/nginx \
    && chown -R adm-app:adm-app /var/run/nginx \
    && chown -R adm-app:adm-app /var/lib/nginx

# Switch to nginx user
USER adm-app

# Expose port application
EXPOSE 9090

# Running nginx web server
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

